# How do I account for the change in orientation size for an Android spinner?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-spinner

**My Problem**:
I'm trying to learn Android app development for the company in which I work. However, I'm struggling on how to automate the change in size of a spinner (listbox) upon screen orientation (portrait vs landscape). I thought this was simply handled by using constraints in a constraint layout. However, now I think it may involve some java code but I hadn't found any sort of method for the spinner to account for this change in orientation.

**What I have done**:
I've been practicing, reading and using tutorials throughout the Android app learning experience. Below is an example of the XML spinner code for the "Topic" spinner I have and how I was approaching the design based upon using a constraint layout. I may be doing a couple things wrong but need some direction. Even when I follow the constraint tutorials, I still don't get the same results... so I'm not sure if I may be missing a constraint component of some sort.

**What the goal is**:
The goal is to have a minimum size for the spinner portrait orientation (e.g. 30 x 300) which changes on landscape orientation to a size that fits (e.g. (e.g. 30 x XXX). When I change the height and width to wrap_content, since it is a spinner it simply collapses, but I need it to stay a minimum size on portrait and expand to fit on landscape... you can see I'm not succeeding very well.

The code below is for the "Topic" spinner. I figure once I figure this out I can apply to the rest.

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/cbxSearchTopics"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cbxSearchQuestions"/>
```

[image: Spinner Landscape]
[image: Spinner Portrait]

Comment: "anchor" your textviews to the left side of your layout, and set your spinner's `layout_width` to 0dp

Comment: @user3170251: That worked! Thanks! I was hoping it was that simple. If I remember correctly then, I would just set a margin boundary on the spinner to keep the spinner from butting against the TextArea (i.e. label)?

Comment: sure. You can set your spinner margin on the design tab or in the xml file using `android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User3170251's comment above was the answer/fix.

> "anchor" your textviews to the left side of your layout, and set your spinner's layout_width to 0dp